# Django: lazy loading installed_apps

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm working on a project upgrade from Django 1.8 to 1.11. They've used a custom registration app which is inheriting from Django Registration Redux package.
Both packages are listed on installed_apps list. All works fine however when I try to run tests, where it creates test tables back to back, it errors at the following lines:

```
....
Creating table profile_preferences
Creating table registration_registrationprofile
Creating table registration_registrationprofile
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "registration_registrationprofile" already exists
```

This is because both Apps are listed within the installed_apps list. Is there a way around this?

Removing the django-registration-redux from installed_apps causes `RuntimeError: Model class registration.models.RegistrationProfile doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.` error.

Comment: What do you mean "Is it possible to add/remove installed_apps" ??? What's your problem actually ?

Comment: I've explanined the problem, because of inheritence used, models are actually installed but not specified as an element of installed_apps list. Any reference to it causes an ```RuntimeError: Model class registration.models.RegistrationProfile doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.``` error.

Comment: No you did not explained the problem (not in your question - you just did in your comment). Please edit your question to include your comment.

Comment: Also, have you tried adding a `app_label` in your model class ?

Comment: Which version of registration redux are you using (or migrating to)? Looks like this is a known issue (that never seems to have a good answer). https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/88

Comment: I am using version 2.0. I've forked the repo and will add in the app_label declaration to see if that makes a difference. I will update this post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers I've forked the project and added in app_label to meta class which solved the issue.

Comment: Actually you needn't fork the whole project - you could just have monkeypatched the models.meta in your own registration app's models.py.

Comment: I've forked it for different reasons but thanks for the suggestion.